# How to find record in top n rows ordered by desc

Tags: sql, jdbc

I want to select top n rows ordered by DESC then need to find the record surround= '' exist in those top n rows in jdbc SQL query below is the table for reference.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM fchild where vehicle='43' ORDER BY id DESC) where vehicle = '43' AND surround ='16';
```

```
vehicle  surround  Iter id
31        31         1  1
31        65         2  2
6         6          1  3
6        74          1  4
34       34          1  5
43       43          2  6
37       37          1  7
37       73          1  8
43       16          1  9
80        7          2  10
62       62          1  11
43       35          1  12
```

Comment: What is your expected output based on this input and why?

Comment: The outer `where vehicle = '43'` can be removed, it's the same in the Derived Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM fchild where vehicle='43' ORDER BY id DESC) a where vehicle = '43' AND surround ='16';
```

It will work for me. You forgot the name of subquery(in my example is it 'a'). Did I understand the problem correctly?